# PHP error calling a function from a package

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I am new to php and have just installed my first package via composer. I'm now trying to call a function from the package I installed as follows:

```
<?php
  require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
  $value = 1;
  $aws = AmazonGiftCode::make()->buyGiftCard($value);
  echo $aws;
?>
```

But I get the following error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'AmazonGiftCode' not found in
> /public_html/php/test.php:4 Stack trace:
> #0 {main}   thrown in /public_html/php/test.php on line 4

Based on my (albeit limited) experience with other languages, I'm guessing I have to load the package that contains the class first. The package folder is in the same directory as the test.php file, in the subfolder `vendor/kamerk22/AmazonGiftCode/`. But I think this is where I don't know enough to troubleshoot it based on the information I could find.

Comment: Depends on the auotloader, it should load it if setup correctly.  Maybe `AmazonGiftCode` needs to be in `venor/`?  Check the `autoload.php` code to see where it expects it to be.

Comment: How did you installed this package? It should be in `vendor/kamerk22/amazongiftcode/` (case matters).

Comment: I installed it using `composer require` and I see the package files in `vendor/kamerk22/amazongiftcode`.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Looks like you forgot to import the class using `use`

Comment: I've tried loading it explicitly with `use \vendor\kamerk22\amazongiftcode\src\` which gives the same class not found error (`Uncaught Error: Class 'AmazonGiftCode' not found`). I've tried to specify the file that defines the class `use \vendor\kamerk22\amazongiftcode\src\AmazonGiftCode` and that gives the error `Uncaught Error: Class 'vendor\kamerk22\amazongiftcode\src\AmazonGiftCode' not found` I've tried all variations of `vendor\kamerk22`, `\vendor\kamerk22\amazongiftcode` that I could think of. I've also double-checked that that file indeed defines the class.

Answer (score 0):

Your directory structure should look like this.

```
test.php
composer.json
vendor
└───autoload.php
└───kamerk22
    └───AmazonGiftCode
```

Make sure you installed the package using composer, and not by downloading it.

> I'm guessing I have to load the package that contains the class first.

Unlike what you would normally expect when importing stuff, when using composer you only have to import the autoload.php file, and composer will take care of loading other packages as needed. By as needed what I mean is that as soon as composer sees you use the AmazonGiftCode class it will import the AmazonGiftCode package, but if one of your REST endpoints doesn't use anything from the AmazonGiftCode package it won't ever load it. This allows you to not have to worry about slowing down the entire application when you want to use a composer package for only a few endpoints. At least that's the way I understand how composer works.

Comment: I have installed using the composer, and the file structure looks mostly like that. Except that it's `kamerk22\amazongiftcode` (all small) which contains multiple files. The class is defined in `kamerk22\amazongiftcode\src\AmazonGiftCode.php`

Comment: Try adding `use kamerk22\AmazonGiftCode;` after you require the autoload file.

Answer (score 0):

Just run [`composer dump-autoload`](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload-dumpautoload-) once and the class should known then.

You could also get verbose and `use kamerk22\AmazonGiftCode\AmazonGiftCode;`

But that [AmazonGiftCode](https://github.com/kamerk22/AmazonGiftCode) looks quite Laravel specific... that's why it may still fail, even if it may be found by auto-load. One needs to setup Laravel framework in the first place; just see this [query](https://github.com/kamerk22/AmazonGiftCode/search?q=Illuminate&unscoped_q=Illuminate) (just in case if you may wonder where all these missing classes may come from).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I have tried composer dump-autoload with no luck. I installed Laravel using Softalicious. The frontpage/index for that seems to load fine.